# powercli: how to list the vcenters connected to vcloud director

Tags: powershell, powercli

I need to list all vcenters connected to vcloud director via powercli but I can't find a way to do it.
This is supposed to be trivial: any help is appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: Actually this is the answer: search-cloud -querytype virtualcenter

Comment: A colleague gave me this one liner: search-cloud is super powerful and super fast

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What version of PowerCLI are you using currently? Probably doesn't matter much but I would suggest that you make sure you are using the latest version to ensure all the help files are up to date and you have all the cmdlet improvements.

That said, you have to first connect to a cluster or whatever your vcenter host is, then run the `search-cloud -QueryType VirtualCenter` command. That is a valid answer so I'm not sure why the other post was down-voted.

Comment: You are right Bill, thanks. Indeed I use the last versions of the apis

Comment: Glad I could help, even if just a little.

Answer (score 0):

These below links should give you the set off along with the explanation of each script:

1. [VCloud Reporting Org 1](http://anthonyspiteri.net/vcloud-reporting-org-and-orgvdc-vm-report-powercli/)
2. [VCloud Reporting Org 2](http://virtualize-automate.com/wp/index.php/2016/01/03/calculate-vcloud-director-vm-utilization-metrics-using-powercli/)
3. [Relating VCloud Director to Vcenter](http://www.virtu-al.net/2013/03/08/relating-vcloud-director-to-vcenter-in-powercli/)

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Actually this is the answer: 
search-cloud -querytype virtualcenter
search-cloud is super fast!